# Steam says drive is not mounted with executive permissions

Tags: mount, permissions, games, steam, sd-card

I can't seem to get steam to allow me to install games on my SD Card.
I use this command to mount it:

```
sudo mount -o exec /dev/sda1 /home/spib/SDCard
```

Steam still gives the "New Steam library folder must be mounted on a filesystem with executive permissions" message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file system is on `/dev/sda1`? What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f /dev/sda1`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to format it with a unix filesystem instead of fat32.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried doing that with `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1` and then `mount -o exec,rw /dev/sda1 /home/spib/SDCard` but now it says the drive is read-only. `fdisk -l` also reveals that it is still formatted as FAT32.

Comment: @Spib: Please add the info about the file system type to your question. Also, the formatting problem looks like a subsequent but separate issue for which you should [open a new question](/questions/ask).

Comment: @Spib, `fdisk -l` only shows the partition type code, which is used by windows but not linux.  Also check `dmesg` for more detailed error messages after mounting the filesystem.